while calling a function in another function .but we have to return the both values in the function
while we calling a function in another function
 function1(){
return this.a
}
function2(){
 return this.b
}

if we want  output in string this method is used
we can recall the function1 in function2
function2(){
var resultOfFunction1 = this.function1();
return resultOfFunction1.toString() + ' ' + this.b.toString();
}

for array
function2() {
var resultOfFunction1 = this.function1(); // Assuming this is a method that returns a value
return [resultOfFunction1, this.b];
}

for object
function2() {
  console.log(this.a);
  var resultOfFunction1 = this.function1(); // Assuming this is a method that returns a value
  return {
    valueOfFunction1: resultOfFunction1,
    valueOfB: this.b
  };
}

we want to return the both function values

So what's your question here?

you could create a new function that calls both
functionBoth() {
    return [this.function1(), this.function2()];//it will show in array
}

